# Two List properties, unable to to create a list using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I am not sure how I would be able to Select through two list properties in a class like:

```
public class AddAssignMealView
{
    public int TraineeID { get; set; }
    public List<int> MealID { get; set; }
    public List<string> Day { get; set; }
}
```

And create a list() where it is one TraineeID, one MealID, and one Day. I managed to do it with MealID list (below), but when I added the Day list I am unsure of what do. Any Ideas?

```
AddAssignMealView mealtraiDeserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddAssignMealView>(mealTrainee);

                meals = mealtraiDeserializeObject.MealID.Select(x => new MealTrainee()
                {
                    TraineeID = mealtraiDeserializeObject.TraineeID,
                    MealID = x
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Will `MealID` and `Day` always be the same length? What is the type `MealTrainee`?

Comment: Yes, they will always be the same length. `MealID` is associated with the `Day`. EX: Monday: Tacos(MealID of 20).

Comment: BTW, wouldn't that be better as `MealIDs` and `Days`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Enumerable.Zip` function to combine two `List`s:

```
var ans = mealtraiDeserializeObject.MealID.Zip(mealtraiDeserializeObject.Day, (m, d) => new {
    mealtraiDeserializeObject.TraineeID,
    MealID = m,
    Day = d
}).ToList();
```

You could also use the (rarely mentioned) two argument version of `Enumerable.Select`, but I don't think the minuscule improvement in efficiency is worth the (IMO) decrease in readability:

```
var ans = mealtraiDeserializeObject.MealID.Select((m, i) => new {
    mealtraiDeserializeObject.TraineeID,
    MealID = m,
    Day = mealtraiDeserializeObject.Day[i]
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Threw an error saying "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: second"

Comment: That sounds like your `Day` doesn't have any values.